# Using inheritance to provide one class by another in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to become a self taught developer, so I have nobody to ask when I do not understand the task in a course. The question is about inheritance.
Given structure[image]

I have to implement some classes as a piece of program to monitor news.
I was given the base abstract class Trigger

```
class Trigger(object):
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        # DO NOT CHANGE THIS!
        raise NotImplementedError
```

And then I have to implement other classes accordingly the scheme. I did it like that:

```
class PhraseTrigger(Trigger):
    
    def __init__(self, trigger, story):
        self._trigger = trigger
        self._story = story
    
    def is_phrase_in(self):

        phrase_to_match = r"((\W)+|^)"
        for i in self._trigger.split():
            phrase_to_match += i
            if (i != self._trigger.split()[-1]):
                phrase_to_match += r"(\W)+"
            else:
                phrase_to_match += r"((\W)+|$)"

        # print(phrase_to_match) # delete after debugging
        scheme_to_match = re.compile(phrase_to_match, re.IGNORECASE)
        mo = scheme_to_match.search(self._story)

        if (mo != None):
            return True
        else:
            return False
        
    def evaluate(self, story):
        """
        Returns True if an alert should be generated
        for the given news item, or False otherwise.
        """
        
        if is_phrase_in(self):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I've done all of them except Not-, And- and OrTrigger.
Next I was said "The NotTrigger should produce its output by inverting the output of another trigger. The NOT trigger should take this other trigger as an argument to its constructor". How can I add another class to **init** method of NotTrigger? Or I did not catch the idea completely. Any advice will be appreciated.
P.S. Sorry for long text and my poor English(it's my second language).

Comment: Please observe how we edited your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `NotTrigger.__init__` takes an *instance* of `Trigger` as its argument. Once you have that, you can implement `NotTrigger.evaluate` in terms of the other trigger's `evaluate` method. Something like

```
class NotTrigger:
    def __init__(self, trigger):
        self.trigger = trigger


    def evaluate(self, story):
        if self.trigger.evaluate(story):
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

Note that it's not `__init__` that should take a `story` argument, only `evaluate`. If a `Trigger` wraps another `Trigger` (or more than one), it's `evaluate`'s job to ensure that the wrapped `Trigger`'s `evaluate` method is called on `story` when appropriate.

Comment: Shouldn't the "not" trigger simply negate the assessment of the target trigger?

Comment: Well, yes. But I didn't want to come right out and say that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with a simple implementation of `NotTrigger`. Here is how you would define an initializer (technically not the constructor) that accepts another trigger:

```
class NotTrigger:
    def __init__(self, trigger):
        self.trigger = trigger
```

Now the `evaluate` method should be trivial:

```
def evaluate(self, story):
    return not self.trigger.evaluate(story)
```

Hopefully you now see some of the problems with your implementation of `PhraseTrigger`:

1. `PhraseTrigger` should not accept neither another trigger as an argument to `__init__`, nor the story.
2. `PhraseTrigger` should not directly implement `evaluate`: that's up to the child classes.
3. `PhraseTrigger` should accept a phrase to search for.
4. `PhraseTrigger` should provide a method `is_phrase_in(self, text)` to search for `self.phrase` in `text`. Child classes will determine what to pass in for `text`.